# How can I copy to clipboard (from a ViewHolder)?

Tags: java, android

I tried to copy the text from the ViewHolder (not onclick):

```
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager);
getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("label", "Text to copy");
clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
```

And it can recognize -`getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE)`

Comment: you mean it cannot recognize? Was it a typo?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("Label", "The text to be copied.");
                if (clipboard != null) {
                    clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
                }
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Your message copied!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Usually, replace "The text to be copied." part as something toString() (for example something that shown in TextView) if this has a real usage.

You are only missing "Context." in your code. This should work.

Comment: Still can't recognize -getSystemService